# Pivot pandas dataframe to have multi-indexed columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, multi-index

I am struggling with how to pivot the dataframe to have multi-indexed columns.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"name":["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b",  "c", "c"], 
                     "month":[1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3], 
                     "buy_sell":["sell", "buy", "sell", "buy", "sell", "buy", "sell", "buy"],
                     "value":[10, 20, 30, 40, 20, 80, 50, 60]})
data
```

[image]

And I want to pivot this to a wide format. index is `name`, and for columns I want to create multi-index with the combination of `month` and `buy_sell`

[image]

Or if not multi-indexed columns, I want to pivot the dataframe so that the columns have the suffices such as `sell_1`, `buy_1`, `sell_2`, `buy_2` etc...

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `data.pivot('name', ['month', 'buy_sell'], 'value')`. This will create your multi-index columns

Comment: I get `KeyError: 'Level month not found'`...

Comment: Then your column is not `'month'` but it could have trailing whitespace like `'month '` You will need to do `data.columns` to see the actual names of your columns

Comment: @It_is_Chris you may need to use `pivot_table` instead of `pivot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set_index()` and `unstack()`:

```
(data.set_index(['name','month','buy_sell'])['value']
      .unstack(['month','buy_sell']))
```

Output:

```
month        1           2     3
buy_sell  sell   buy  sell   buy
name                            
a         10.0  20.0   NaN   NaN
b         20.0  80.0  30.0  40.0
c         50.0   NaN   NaN  60.0
```

If you insist on having those columns with all `NaN`, you can `unstack` one level at a time:

```
(data.set_index(['name','month','buy_sell'])['value']
      .unstack('month').unstack('buy_sell')
     )
```

Output:

```
month        1         2           3     
buy_sell   buy  sell buy  sell   buy sell
name                                     
a         20.0  10.0 NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
b         80.0  20.0 NaN  30.0  40.0  NaN
c          NaN  50.0 NaN   NaN  60.0  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! Your second answer is exactly what I needed :)